# Windows 2008 and Remote Management Console

Tags: windows-server-2008

The interface has changed and maybe I'm being dense, but I haven't seen where to do this yet.

I just installed my first Windows 2008 server. On Windows 2003 and below, I can right click on My Computer, go to manage, and from there right click on the (local) computer and change to any remote NT-based computer and read the logs, manage services, etc...

I can't for the life of me find it under 2008. Looks like the management console was replaced with some kind of server management console, and I don't see where it can connect and read logs/stats on remote systems.

This is Windows 2008 x64 standard.

Comment: I hadn't looked at that yet, but it seems as if you're only going to be able to get useful info out of OTHER 2008 servers.  Connecting to 2003 returns a lot of garbage.  Dang.

Comment: I created a batch file on the desktop that just has "start compmgmt.msc" in it (since when I launched compmgmt I couldn't find an option to save the file for later launching). I just checked and could connect to an older version to read the logs, etc...so it should work using that utility.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
Compmgmt.msc
```

Then right click the top of the tree, and choose 'Connect to another computer'

Comment: Bingo! I think that was the console I was looking for, although Maxwell's response had the snapins listed for viewing remote shares (which I needed at the moment). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Launching mmc from command line and importing the corresponding mmc snap-in will to the trick. You'll be prompted if you want to connect to the local or a remote computer.

EDIT: I think that the functionnality you're seeking is only available on 2008 R2 servers, see this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378896(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: just to clarify...you're saying I'm not being dense and overlooking the feature, but rather the functionality in pre-2008 servers was removed?

Comment: Just edited my post, sorry for being unclear.